# Requesting send email verification using firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, email-validation

I am trying to send an email verification when the user sign up, here's my code under provider/user.ts

```
onCreate(form: NgForm) {
var user = new User();
user.name = form.value.name;
user.email = form.value.email;
user.contact = form.value.contact;

if(form.value.gender == "male") {
  user.gender = "male";
} else {
  user.gender = "female"
}
let loading = this.mProv.getLoader('Creating your account...', 0);
loading.present();
this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(form.value.email, form.value.password)
.then( res=> {
  let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  user.sendEmailVerification();
})
  .then(data => {
    user.id = data.uid;
    this.userProvider.addUser(user)
      .then(_ =>
        loading.dismiss()
      )
      .catch(error => {
        loading.dismiss();
        this.mProv.showAlertOkMessage('Error','Sign up error. Please try again later.');
      });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    loading.dismiss();
    this.mProv.showAlertOkMessage('Error','Sign up error. Please try again later.');
  });
}
```

I don't know where to put user.sendEmailVerification, the data.uid gets red underline when I put

```
 .then( res=> {
  let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  user.sendEmailVerification();
})
```

will appreciate all help.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `.then(data => { ... })`, the argument for `data` is whatever was returned by the previous stage of the chain, but the stage you inserted with `user.sendEmailVerification()` does not return anything.  If you don't want to wait for the `user.sendEmailVerification()` to complete, then you can just move that code into the next stage rather than using a separate stage:

```
this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(form.value.email, form.value.password)
  .then(data => {
    let firebaseUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification();
    user.id = data.uid;
    this.userProvider.addUser(user)
      .then(_ =>
        loading.dismiss()
      )
      .catch(error => {
        loading.dismiss();
        this.mProv.showAlertOkMessage('Error','Sign up error. Please try again later.');
      });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    loading.dismiss();
    this.mProv.showAlertOkMessage('Error','Sign up error. Please try again later.');
  });
```

Alternatively, you could use `async`/`await` instead of `then` for a much easier-to-follow programming style.  Here's [one very basic tutorial](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/async-and-await-in-typescript) that I found in a [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=typescript+convert+then+to+async+await).

Comment: thank you for the explanation, as you have said it does not return anything, the `user.id` and `.addUser(user)` got an error, so to put it simple i should wright another function? `async userVerified() { let user = firebase.auth().currentUser; await user.sendEmailVerification();} ` sorry to bother you, i'm really a beginner, i'll look up the link you gave me, thank you for the help.

Comment: Oops, I didn't mean to shadow the outer `user` variable.  See the updated answer.  Using a separate function to send the email verification is also a good approach.

Comment: it does do something to my application, but it does not sending any messages to my email, and should i add `firebaseUser = user;` after `sendEmailVerification()`? because the reg user does not show up on the database

Comment: I don't know how to troubleshoot this.  You could consider submitting a new question, but it's going to be hard for anyone to help unless you can narrow the problem down further or provide a complete example that someone else can run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: alright i will create a new question, thank you for the help

Comment: I see the new question and I don't have the background to help with it.